# Symfony Session Initialization

Tags: php, symfony, session

Currently, when needed, I'm initializing the session with the following code:

```
if (!$request->hasSession()) {
    $this->logger->debug("starting new session");
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();
    $request->setSession($session);
}
```

Is there a simple way to initialize the session only when needed?

I was thinking something like `$request->getSession(true)` in order to create it if not existing. Or even a listener that will create the session at the beginning of each request.

Is there any alternative or good practice?

Comment: Technically `$request->getSession()` should be all you need. Here's a quote from documentation `While it is recommended to explicitly start a session, a session will actually start on demand, that is, if any session request is made to read/write session data.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you want to meddle with `Session` you should see the [Session Management docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html).